# Unresolved reference: javax.inject in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, javax.inject

I'm new to Android Studio and this might be a very basic question but I would like to better understand what is happening.

I'm trying to copy over some functionality from an example project - (https://github.com/android/architecture-samples  - main branch). That code uses @Singleton and @Inject annotations from the javax.inject library. What I can't figure out is how this library is added to the project.

Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2

Example project  Gradle  version: 7.5

My project Gradle version: 8.0

Example project gradle.build (:app) file:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2020 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kapt)
    alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)
}

android {
    compileSdk = libs.versions.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.main"
        minSdk = libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInt()
        targetSdk = libs.versions.targetSdk.get().toInt()
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.CustomTestRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += "room.incremental" to "true"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("debug") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isTestCoverageEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            testProguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguardTest-rules.pro")
        }

        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
            testProguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguardTest-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    // Always show the result of every unit test, even if it passes.
    testOptions.unitTests {
        isIncludeAndroidResources = true

        all { test ->
            with(test) {
                testLogging {
                    events = setOf(
                        org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.PASSED,
                        org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.SKIPPED,
                        org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.FAILED,
                        org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.STANDARD_OUT,
                        org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.logging.TestLogEvent.STANDARD_ERROR,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        excludes += "META-INF/AL2.0"
        excludes += "META-INF/LGPL2.1"
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.androidxComposeCompiler.get()
    }

    tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn"
            freeCompilerArgs += "-opt-in=kotlin.Experimental"
        }
    }
}

/*
 Dependency versions are defined in the top level build.gradle file. This helps keeping track of
 all versions in a single place. This improves readability and helps managing project complexity.
 */
dependencies {

    // App dependencies
    implementation(libs.androidx.annotation)
    implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)
    implementation(libs.timber)
    implementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.idling.resources)

    // Architecture Components
    implementation(libs.room.runtime)
    implementation(libs.room.ktx)
    ksp(libs.room.compiler)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtimeCompose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewModelCompose)

    // Hilt
    implementation(libs.hilt.android.core)
    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.navigation.compose)
    kapt(libs.hilt.compiler)

    // Jetpack Compose
    val composeBom = platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom)

    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.compiler)
    implementation(composeBom)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.foundation.core)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.foundation.layout)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.animation)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.material.core)
    implementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.compose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtimeCompose)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewModelCompose)
    implementation(libs.accompanist.appcompat.theme)
    implementation(libs.accompanist.swiperefresh)

    debugImplementation(composeBom)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui.tooling.core)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui.test.manifest)

    // Dependencies for local unit tests
    testImplementation(composeBom)
    testImplementation(libs.junit4)
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.archcore.testing)
    testImplementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)
    testImplementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.test)
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.navigation.testing)
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.core)
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.contrib)
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.intents)
    testImplementation(libs.google.truth)
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui.test.junit)

    // JVM tests - Hilt
    testImplementation(libs.hilt.android.testing)
    kaptTest(libs.hilt.compiler)

    // Dependencies for Android unit tests
    androidTestImplementation(composeBom)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.junit4)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.test)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.compose.ui.test.junit)

    // AndroidX Test - JVM testing
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.test.core.ktx)
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext)
    testImplementation(libs.androidx.test.rules)
    testImplementation(project(":shared-test"))

    // AndroidX Test - Instrumented testing
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.core.ktx)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.rules)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.room.testing)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.archcore.testing)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.navigation.testing)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.contrib)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.intents)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.idling.resources)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.espresso.idling.concurrent)
    androidTestImplementation(project(":shared-test"))

    // AndroidX Test - Hilt testing
    androidTestImplementation(libs.hilt.android.testing)
    kaptAndroidTest(libs.hilt.compiler)
}
```

I fixed the  "unresolved reference inject" error thrown up by Android Studio by simply manually adding
"implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'"
to the dependencies block in the build.gradle (:app) file in my project but there is nothing of that kind or any explicit reference to javax or inject anywhere in the example project's build.gradle files an yet there Android Studio has not trouble finding it.

I also tried simply copying all the dependencies from from the example project by then I get
"could not get unknown property 'libs'" when trying to build the project. I think this might depend on the these few lines of code:

```
/**
 * Retrieves the [libs][org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs] extension.
 */
val org.gradle.api.Project.`libs`: org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs get() =
    (this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.getByName("libs") as org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs

/**
 * Configures the [libs][org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs] extension.
 */
fun org.gradle.api.Project.`libs`(configure: Action<org.gradle.accessors.dm.LibrariesForLibs>): Unit =
    (this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions.configure("libs", configure)
```

somewhere in a
C:\Users\Owner.gradle\caches\7.5\kotlin-dsl\accessors\01fe2eed4467b292cb55edf16f388a3c\sources\org\gradle\kotlin\dsl\Accessors9lduusevit01i1zyt8g4j1zrv.kt
file but I'm really not sure what any of this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project you linked uses [Gradle Version Catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html) to declare the dependencies. The dependencies are declared in the `gradle/libs.version.toml` file instead of the `build.gradle` file. I think you haven't set up the version catalog properly. Please check out [this version catalog file](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/main/gradle/libs.versions.toml) and add this to your project.

The `javax.inject.Inject` dependency is provided by the [Java JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/package-summary.html). You do not need to add any dependency for it. Hilt uses this under the hood for dependency injection, and you already have the [Hilt dependencies](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android).

Comment: Thanks. I understand better what is going on in the example project now. However I think I'm just going to leave the manually added dependency (i.e. "implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'") as I just can't find a way to get rid of the  "unresolved reference to inject" when trying to build my project without it.  The JDK used by my project is "Android Studio Java Home, JetBrains Runtime version 17.0.6". Maybe this has something to do with it. I have no idea. In any case the project works and I understand dependencies better now. Thanks again.